# Stripping tags from an XML string and using as Alias

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Ok, I've been messing around with this for awhile now but I can't seem to get it to work. That, or it just isn't possible

Given the following T-SQL I want to Strip the <> tags and use what is inside as an Alias. Possible? I was thinking a nested replace to strip it but no clue how to use the result as the alias. The whole goal is to just define the html tags in the SET statements and have it auto populate the alias and the column indicator in the table variable. If there is a better/easier way that isn't to involved like xpath, I'm open.

```
Use Database
DECLARE @First VARCHAR(15), @Second VARCHAR(15),@XMLTag varchar(15)
SET @First = '<InstrumentID>'
SET @Second = '</InstrumentID>'
SET @XMLTag = Replace(Replace,@first,'<',''),@first,'>','') 

select *
from 
(
        SELECT out_interface_id, msg_id , 
        SUBSTRING(xml_msg, CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) + LEN(@First), 
                 CHARINDEX(@Second, xml_msg) - 
                 CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) - 
                 LEN(@First)) as @XMLTag,
        msg_type, xml_msg, CAST(xml_msg AS XML) as [Quick_XML], 
        date_received,status, last_modified, environment,
        transaction_closed_date
        from Table1 with (nolock)
        where msg_type in ('BALMIS','ACCTV21') 
        and date_received >= CAST(GETDATE() -1 as DATE)
        and date_received < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
) x
where x.@XMLTag = 'ABC123'
order by date_received desc
```

Comment: There is a syntaxe error in the assign statement of @XMLtag. Consider fixing it.

Comment: To make the alias work, you will need dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have dynamic alias, you need dynamic SQL.

After building the query in a VARCHAR(MAX) variable, you can use 
procedure [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms188001.aspx) to execute the builded query.

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @First VARCHAR(15)
SELECT  @First = '<InstrumentID>'

SELECT @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT ''WhatEver'' AS ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@First, '<', ''), '>', '') + '
                      FROM [InsertYourFromStatementHere]
                      WHERE x.@XMLTag = ''ABC123''
                      ORDER BY date_received DESC'

PRINT @DynamicSQL

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
```

Execute the query above and it will fail because [InsertYourFromStatementHere] and x doesn't exist. However, you will see in the output the dynamic SQL generated. Modify the query until you get one that run and do what you want.

Beaware that this open a door for SQL injection.